# onPopState() throwing error only in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm using AJAX to refresh content on pages and so trying to us the history API in HTML5. I have this working fine in all browsers apart from Google Chrome. The following code -

```
/**
 * Reloads the ajax content if the history.state is not null
 */
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state !== null){
        initiate_load_updated_page(window.history.state.ajax_string, window.history.state.security, 0)
    }
}
```

Produces this error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax_string' of undefined
```

Here is the code that I am using for `pushState()` -

```
/** Update the page history */
if(window.history.replaceState){ // Check for HTML5 support
    if(update_state !== 0){
        var object = {
            ajax_string: ajax_string,
            security: security,
        };
        window.history.pushState(object, title, permalink);
    }
}
```

I have read elsewhere that Google Chrome triggers an `onPopState()` event twice, but I'm not sure if this is the promblem here, and, if it is, how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you testing if `e.state` is null but then using `window.history.state`?  Do you know that `window.history.state` is not null?  Why not `e.state.ajax_string`?

Comment: You sir, are a genius. That looks to have worked - didn't even think about that!!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `popstate` handler you should be using `e.state` not `window.history.state`:

```
if(e.state !== null){
    initiate_load_updated_page(e.state.ajax_string, e.state.security, 0)
}
```